# C++ weird third-party function constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, ginac

I have a third-party library, and I want to use one of the supplied constructors.

**ex.h:**

```
/** Construct example from string and a list of symbols. The input grammar is
 *  similar to the GiNaC output format. All symbols and indices to be used
 *  in the expression must be specified in a lst in the second argument.
 *  Undefined symbols and other parser errors will throw an exception.        */
ex(const std::string &s, const ex &l);
```

I tried the following:

```
symbol x("x");

ex e("x^2",x);
```

Unfortunately the usage of this constructor is incorrect. I get the following error message:

> **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: find_or_insert_symbol: symbol "x" not found**

All documentation that is provided is the comment above the declaration. I am a C++ novice, so I have no idea what is wrong.

I tried the suggestion in the first answer like the following:

```
symbol x("x");

ex expression;
ex e("x^2",expression);

std::cout << diff(e,x) << std::end
```

This results in the following error message:

> **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: find_or_insert_symbol: symbol "x" not found
>   (lldb)**

**Note**: I tried using *e* and *expression* in *diff()*.

Comment: Seems that there has to be another way to get an `ex` other than this constructor.

Comment: "unfortunately it doesn't work" - never say this when posting a question here. What doesn't work? What exact error messages are you getting?

Comment: Does this third party provide any documentation? The second paramater for the ex constructor is an ex itself. Is symbol an ex?

Comment: http://www.ginac.de/tutorial/#Expressions

Comment: http://www.ginac.de/reference/classGiNaC_1_1ex.html

Comment: See my edits ! And thank you for your advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an `ex` reference, not a `symbol` reference;
Try this:

```
ex MyEx1; //This will call to the ex default constructor for MyEx1, if it exist.
ex e("x^2",MyEx1); //This will call to the ex constructor that you want to use for e.
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument should be a list of symbols occuring in the string (more precisely, a GiNaC::ex handling a GiNaC::lst). This works:

```
    symbol x("x");
    ex e("x^2", lst{x});
```

The idea is that it should work with more than just one symbol:

```
    symbol x("x"), y("y");
    ex e("x^2-2*x*y+y^2", lst{x,y});
    cout << diff(e, x) << endl;  // prints "2*x-2*y" or similar
```